# How Can I update the value of property of an observable in reducer?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I want to update the state of all mydirect message with specific user when i start an event,
how can i update this property with filtering only this user and the messages which are not seen yet...thanks

```
 //----------State Message---------------//
   //----------State Message---------------//
 on(directMessagesAction.seenMyRecievedMessage, (state, { payload }) => {
    const messages = [...state.allDirectMessages];
    for (let m of messages) {
      if (
        m.messageModel.from.userName == payload.userName &&
        m.messageModel.isSeen == false
      ) {
        m.messageModel.isSeen = true;
      }
    }

    return { ...state, allDirectMessages: messages };
  }),
```

this is the model of directMessage

```
import { MessageViewModel } from "./messageViewModel";
import { OnlineUserModel } from "./onlineUserModel";
export class DirectMessage {
  public fromOnlineUser: OnlineUserModel | null = {
    userName: "",
    email: "",
    firstname: "",
    profilePic: "",
    isProfileComplete: "",
    isActive: "",
  };
  public messages = "";

  public messageModel: MessageViewModel = {
    content: "",
    timestamp: "",
    from: null,
    to: null,
    avatar: "",
    attachement: "",
    fileSize: "",
    fileNameSaved: "",
    isSeen: false,
    isSeenDate: "",
  };
  ////-------- ***** try with message Oject *****------/////
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Try to elaborate that further. In general, you can update the state in a reducer, which then triggers the views to reload because they observe the state via Observables/Selectors.

Comment: So it is not about ngrx but the logic in general? Just log the state before returning it (or use a breakpoint) and check if it is set to isSeen like u expected

Comment: Thank you Mr Deitsch but if you can clear with code ...

Comment: I'm trying to help you to help yourself. Check if the object you return is correct or not

Comment: I have this Error :Cannot assign to read only property 'messageModel' of object '[object Object]' ... allDirectMessage array of DirectMessage

Comment: I wrote an answer explaining the issue. I'm pretty sure this is the reason but i can't test it rn so it might need another edit or syntax fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't change the state you get passed by the method. It is read-only. As a result your changes to `state.allDirectMessages` cause the error.

> Cannot assign to read only property 'messageModel' of object '[object Object]' ... allDirectMessage array of DirectMessage

The easiest solution is to make a copy of the part you want to change and then override it afterwards.

```js
on(directMessagesAction.seenMyRecievedMessage, (state, { payload }) => {
    const messages = [...state.allDirectMessages]
    for (let m of messages) {
        if (m.messageModel.from.userName == payload.userName && m.messageModel.isSeen == false) {
            m.messageModel.isSeen = true;
        }
    }

    return { ...state, allDirectMessages: messages };
  }),
```

**EDIT:**
my replication of the logic

```js
const messages: Message[] = [
    { sender: 'Me', isSeen: false },
    { sender: 'You', isSeen: false }
]

// map solution
const updated = messages.map(m => ({ ...m, isSeen: true } as Message))
console.log(updated);

// loop solution
for (let m of messages) {
    m.isSeen = true;
}
console.log(messages);
```

Comment: i have this error : ERROR TypeError: allDirectMessagesCopy.forEach is not a function

Comment: updated it, messages should have been an array not an object (switched `{}` for `[]`)

Comment: Sorry but the error consist : TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'isSeen' of object

Comment: updated - i think the `.forEach` does not let u change the object. Just iterate the object with an loop.

Comment: Sorry but the same error...

Comment: Add you model and update your implementation in the question, i've tested the logic and it works in my environment

Comment: in your example I have to add isSeen property in DirectMessage, but i have this property in messageModel, how can I access to messageModel properties and change it,

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's a sub-model. Update your question with your model pls

Comment: I am sure the issue has to do you using classes while i use interfaces. It's copy by reference vs copy by value. Anyway you should use interfaces in NgRx since methods get stripped when serialized.

Comment: That means i should change all classes to interfaces??

Comment: It still impossible, the same error with interfaces

Comment: If you create a stackblitz i can have a look. I can't help you w/o looking at it myself since it works for me.

Comment: Ok bro I will try and see tomorrow

Comment: It looks like we must use nested reducer for deep copy I read this article and I think about other solution... this is the link

Comment: [link](https://medium.com/@splincode/immutable-state-in-ngxs-part-ii-bf249929e5fb)

Comment: It's what i thought it is. It is about copy by reference. The problem is that the spread operator does not copy referenced objects according to the articel you sent. Try the json workaround mentioned. Should be fine for you object